# Get multi-field foreign on order

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm looking for get dependencies into tables linked by foreign key but in case of multi-field, i need the order between them.

For exemple, PgAdmin when you select a table, he give to you constraints, etc...
like :

[image]

I have already a query for get this but it's wrong when multi-field foreign key

```
SELECT
  tc.constraint_name as nom_fk,
  tc.table_name as table_out,
  kcu.column_name as colonne_out, 
  ccu.table_name AS table_in,
  ccu.column_name AS colonne_in 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
  ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
  ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
  AND ccu.table_name='table';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, we can do this with :

```
                            SELECT
                                kcu_foreign.COLUMN_NAME AS key_out,
                                kcu_primary.COLUMN_NAME AS key_in
                            FROM
                                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS fks
                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu_foreign 
                                  ON fks.TABLE_CATALOG = kcu_foreign.TABLE_CATALOG
                                  AND fks.TABLE_SCHEMA = kcu_foreign.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                  AND fks.TABLE_NAME = kcu_foreign.TABLE_NAME
                                  AND fks.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu_foreign.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc 
                                  ON rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = fks.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                  AND rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = fks.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                  AND rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = fks.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pks 
                                  ON rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = pks.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                  AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pks.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                  AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pks.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu_primary
                                  ON pks.TABLE_CATALOG = kcu_primary.TABLE_CATALOG
                                  AND pks.TABLE_SCHEMA = kcu_primary.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                  AND pks.TABLE_NAME = kcu_primary.TABLE_NAME
                                  AND pks.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu_primary.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                  AND kcu_foreign.ORDINAL_POSITION = kcu_primary.ORDINAL_POSITION 
                            WHERE fks.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_shema'
                                AND fks.TABLE_NAME = 'foreign_table'
                                AND pks.TABLE_NAME = 'primary_table'
                                AND fks.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
                                AND pks.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                ORDER BY fks.constraint_name, kcu_foreign.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

But if you want the order exactly, you need to use pg_catalog.pg_constraint :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html

See columns "conkey" and "confkey"